# Securely store data in a Node CLI app

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, token

I am currently writing a NodeJS command-line app. The app makes an API call and returns some data to the user. Given that this is a public API, the user requires an API token. This CLI will be installed globally on the user's machine via `npm i -g super-cool-api-cli`.

The first time the user runs the CLI they are prompted for the token, and then I store it so that each subsequent time they run it they don't need to put it in. I have provided the user a way to reset it as well. I am storing it in the actual directory of my CLI module, which as stated is installed globally, and it looks something like this:

```
fs.writeFile( __dirname+'/.token.json', JSON.stringify( { "token": token }, null, 2 ), 'utf8', (e)=>{
    // error handling and whatever
});
```

I name the file `.token.json`, using a dot to at least make the file hidden by default.

I guess what I am asking is if there is a better/more secure way of storing sensitive information in a NodeJS command line app, that you would be running more than once. I thought about using things like [environment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) but they seem to expire at the end of the process.

Security considerations are a skill I somewhat lack, but greatly desire to learn more about, so thank you in advance for your tips.

Comment: I need to do a similar thing as you with my node CLI app. I noticed you didn't accept any answer, what did you end up doing? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshPinter We ended up using a module called [buttercup](https://buttercup.pw/) to store data behind a password. [There was little debate](https://github.com/himynameisdave/git-labelmaker/issues/14) about it because it just seemed simple. The project is [over here](https://github.com/himynameisdave/git-labelmaker) and has plenty of active users, so this solution seems to have worked well for us :)

Comment: Interesting... thanks for responding back! Buttercup looks like a nice 1Password replacement. Didn't think about using it's core to store passwords, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I think it's best to use the credential storage facilities provided by the OS for this sort of thing, assuming of course that each user has their own account on the machine. The only NPM package I know that handles that is [node-keytar](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar).

Comment: Sounds pretty legit actually, thanks! So essentially I would create a new "service" on the keychain for my app where I can save the token as a password?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your token in sqlite, and set a username/password for the sqlite.db file, here are the bindings for sqlite `https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3`

Comment: So I'm still going to need the user to locally have a sensitive username/password file right? I'm sorry I'm normally a front-end guy so this DB/security stuff is a bit over my head...

Comment: @DaveLunny no worries.  Yes, you would still need the user to input the username and password, but the stored token will be safe and encrypted on the filesystem (which I thought was the security issue).  For the CLI, you can code up a per-session (in memory, not filesystem) cache of the username/password so that the user only has to put in the username and password once per session (on CLI/terminal window).  That is, the user would only have to put in a username and password the first time the open the terminal and run the CLI app.

Comment: Hmm that is pretty good but I don't really like that it's only stored for a session. That's going to make it less user-friendly but obviously that does solve the issue of an unencrypted token just being stored as a JSON file, and remembering a username/password combo is still better than remembering/copy+pasting a whole token every time. Will look more into this solution, thanks!

Comment: No problem @DaveLunny

Answer (score 1):

The standard place to store such tokens is in the user's `~/.netrc` file (see [specifications here](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html)). Heroku does this for [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication#api-token-storage).
A nice consequence of this standard is that there exist libraries to read/write this file (such as [netrc-rw](https://github.com/treygriffith/netrc-rw)).

Answer (score 0):

A semi-conventional location to store secrets, like keys, is the `.ssh` directory.

- It often has ACLs restricted to the user, and
- your file would follow the related ACL pattern
- the typical files of this directory include unencrypted secret keys.  Nothing prevents you from further encrypting.
- a dot-file in there should not get in the way of typical uses of the directory.